# .htaccess for rewriting a personal system

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't get my head around exactly what I want to do using mod_rewrite.

I want to be able to type in a url such as:

`http://site.com/project/project-title/people/alex-coady`

or

`http://site.com/project/project-title/tasks/task-list-title`

which will then be processed at `handle.php` with the variables available such that:

`$_GET['project'] would equal 'project-title'`

`$_GET['people'] would equal 'alex-coady'` (first example)

`$_GET['tasks'] would equal 'task-list-title'` (second example)

To reiterate: All requests will be managed by `handle.php`, but if any additional variables are tacked onto the URL, first the keyword `people`, `tasks`, `projects` (and any others I manually add) would be checked and the value immediately after them would be added in the form suggested above.

ie. `http://site.com/handle.php?project=project-title&people=alex-coady&tasks=` (first example)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would handle this is to forget about project,people,tasks and pass everything to the handle.php and then process it there, else you could end up having a rewrite rule for each request you add in the future.

So your mod_rewrite would look like:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ handle.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And your handle/router would look something like this (example)

```
<?php 
//Get Route from request
$route = (!isset($_GET['route']))?'':$_GET['route'];

/*Split the parts of the route*/
$parts = explode('/', $route,4);

//http://site.com/project/project-title/people/alex-coady
//http://site.com/project/project-title/tasks/task-list-title

$project    = (isset($parts[0]))?$parts[0]:null; //project/
$p_title    = (isset($parts[1]))?$parts[1]:null; //project-title/
$action     = (isset($parts[2]))?$parts[2]:null; //people or tasks
$sub_action = (isset($parts[3]))?$parts[3]:null; //alex-coady or task-list-title

//Then work with the above variables
?>
```

Comment: This is how I originally had it working, I felt like I'd be better separating the variables in the .htaccess file but you're right - thank you.

Comment: np, this is how 99.9% of MVC patterns work, its better and more systematic to work with the urls within the script then to let an **outsider** like mod_rewire handle our routes

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^project/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ handle.php?project=$1&people=$2&tasks=$3 [L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^project/(.*) handle.php?data=$1 [L]
```

And in `handle.php`

```
 list($project, $task, $people, $foo, $bar) = explode('/', $_GET['data]);
```